# Passing a column of string from one Google Sheet to another and readback corresponding outputs calculated in the second sheet

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 Sheets in the same Google Workbook file:

- Sheet #1 : Contains some string values in cells A1:A100
- Sheet #2: Has already been designed to calculate a numeric output in cell D1 based on the string inputted in cell C1

I want to run a loop which allows passing each entity of Sheet1 A1:A100 one-by-one to Sheet2 C1. Next I want to readback the corresponding Sheet2 output from cell D1 and populate it in Sheet1 cells B1:B100.

Question:
Is there some way to achieve this by coding in Google Sheets itself? If not, is there some other way such as using Python?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about `calculate` of `Sheet #2: Has been designed to calculate a numeric output in cell D1 based on the string inputted in cell C1`. I'm worried that in your situation, the process cost will become high. So, for example, how about retrieving the values from column "A" of "Sheet #1", calculating the values in the script, and outputting the result values to column "B" of "Sheet #1"? But, I cannot understand your `calculate`. So, if this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Keep in mind that while you can see your spreadsheet and know what you mean, we can't see that spreadsheet. So you're talking in generalities; but solutions are built around specifics, not generalities. If you'd like, share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it, or to a sheet setup to closely approximate it and containing enough data to fully illustrate the problem/goal—say, five or ten rows—along with your hand-entered desired results for that data set).

Comment: Why not simple use a custom function, copy it down to every cell in column B?  And if you would specify what the calculation is maybe we could help.

Comment: @Tanaike The "calculate" feature (to get D1 output based on input C1 in Sheet2) is not the issue/concern in this question. This Sheet2 worksheet is working perfectly when operated standalone

Comment: @ErikTyler Just now, I have added a photo for better visualization, Does this give you better idea about what I am seeking?

Comment: @TheWizEd As you can see from the photo I have added just now, I have thousands of rows of calculation going on in Sheet2.  The final output in cell D1 is a accuracy % number.

Comment: I understood your generic goal from the start. What I don't understand is the specifics. Entries like `aaa` and `sdgrf` are not *realistic* representations of your data. `<string input>` and `<final numeric output>` don't shed any light either. This is why I invited you to share a link to a copy of the spreadsheet. I would need to see the *realistic* data and *exactly* what the formulas in C1 and D1 are currently, none of which is conveyed in your image.

Comment: @ErikTyler the strings are ticker symbols for 100 Stocks such as GOOG, FB, XOM etc. So, whether it is aaa or sdgrf or FB or GOOG, it is a string which very much indeed is a realistic representation of my data. Based on these tickers, my Gsheet imports stock market data and does 1000 rows of computation and gives me a "Success%" ratio for my trades in cell D1. I am a bit unsure why are we fixated on the nature of strings in cell A1:A100 or how I implement cell C1, D1. My ques is pretty straigthforward: how to pass variables as a loop to another sheet & import it's output back to first sheet

Comment: You may feel your question is straightforward, but again, that is because you already know fully what you are doing and what you want. I am a pro of decades. I wouldn't be asking you these questions if it were clear. However, it does now feel that you are looking a gift horse in the mouth, so I'll let other contributors help you from here if they feel so inclined.

Comment: @ErikTyler here is link to the Google workbook (it has 2 sheets). In Sheet2, if you enter any ticker such as GOOG or AAPL manually, it calculates and gives a numeric output in cell D1.  Hope this provides what you were asking for. Please let me know. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Af5-pYMFWZ1QtLoaAbPZYMGRvk43JBslUp4KyOFADfA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So let me see if I understand.  You want to take the string from Sheet1!A1, put it in Sheet2!C1, perform your calculation, get the results and put it in B1.  Then do it for A2, A3, ...

Comment: Having seen your spreadsheet, I think it would be wise to have a seperate sheet for each symbol.  I use GOOGLEFINANCE to plot stock prices and trends.  It is unpredictable as to when it will complete so I think trying to loop through a bunch of symbols, replacing data with data for a different symbol and then doing redoing your calculation will be unreliable.

Comment: @TheWizEd Yes you understood my problem statement correctly. I agree that making separate sheet for each ticker symbol would be one way to go but was hoping if i could get some automation work for me to do the heavy lifting (ie... automatically load each ticker one by one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

Here is a Google App Script that will loop through the symbols and return the calculated value from Sheet2!D1.

It is executed from a new menu item Test.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let menu = ui.createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Run Test","runTest");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function runTest() {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let symbols = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    symbols.forEach( symbol => getResults(symbol) );
    symbols = symbols.filter( symbol => symbol[0] !== "" );
    sheet.getRange(1,1,symbols.length,symbols[0].length).setValues(symbols);
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Error in runTest: "+err);
  }
}

function getResults(symbol) {
  try {
    if( symbol[0] === "" ) return;
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    sheet.getRange(1,3).setValue(symbol[0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    symbol[1] = sheet.getRange(1,4).getValue();
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Error in getResults: "+err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [onOpen Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.filtere()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Comment: The code works, thanks a lot!! Question-- which part of the code is indicating that the output be populated in column B of Sheet1? I see references to (1,1)=A1, (1,3)=C1 and (1,4)=D1 but do not see any reference to (1,2)=B1. What if I wanted to use column C Sheet1 to populate the output, not Column B, how do I do that?

Comment: I use getDataRange() to get all values from Sheet1, both column A & B. Then symbols.forEach() loops through each symbol in column A symbol[0]. And puts the result in symbol[1]. And finally puts all results back in getRange(1,1,symbols.length,symbols[0].length).setValues(symbols)